# Change multiple font styles

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a simple function which can help me change multiple font style to suit my needs but I cannot seem to get the argument correct. I am using excel VBA to bring over text and at the same time changing the font style.

```
Function FStyle(test As String)

test.Font.Bold = True
test.Font.Name = "Arial"
test.Font.Size = 16

End Function
```

[image: Error code]

[image: Workbook Error value]

Comment: You misunderstand the idea of Userdefined Functions (UDF). A function can be used as formula for a cell (like Sin or Sum or Count or Now), not to modify the cell format. And even if this would be the case: A string has no Font-Property (a cell has).

Comment: The input should probably be a `Range` (represents one or more worksheet cells), but a UDF takes inputs, uses them to compute a result, and returns that result -- it cannot modify a cell's formatting. A macro can do that.